# AZURE VM Next Generation Firewall

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

as I'm pretty new to AZURE network and VM issues I got one security question:

I created a VM just for having a stonger machine in the cloud for certain operations. This VM is not connected to our local premises in any way or to other AZURE srevices we use.

Now the AZURE security center recommends that I should use a "Next Generation Firewall" for my Virtual Network which was automatically created when I've set up the VM.

Do I really need such a thing in my case?

Thanks for sharing your knowledge and experiences in advance?

Br

Christoph

Comment: well, depends on what you want to achieve

Comment: To expand on 4c74356b41's comment, your other options include using Azure's Network Security Groups and (if a Windows VM) Windows firewall.  To some degree its up to you to assess the pros and cons of the various approaches. There are some materials that help, such as https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/best-practices-network-security and in your case particularly this: https://kvaes.wordpress.com/2015/06/30/setting-up-a-dmz-in-azure-firewall-or-network-security-groups/ (Note there's a UI for Network Security Groups now, so PowerShell skills no longer needed).

Comment: BTW, I'm reluctant to _tell_ you what you need, because this is security and I don't know what you're securing. Hence the suggestion to read up on options yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Security Center may recommend that you add a next generation firewall (NGFW) from a Microsoft partner to increase your security protections. This document walks you through an example of how to do this:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security-center/security-center-add-next-generation-firewall